# How to link libtorrent library to Qt?

Tags: qt

I would like to run qBittorrent source code. When I run it in Qt it says that multiple files "cannot open include file". The include files are all in the libtorrent directory.

Example of error:

> C:\Users***\Desktop\qBittorrent-master\src\misc.h:46: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'libtorrent/version.hpp': No such file or directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this into your qmake project file and then rerun qmake:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:\path\to\libtorrent\includes
LIBS += -LC:\path\to\libtorrent\lib -ltorrent
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Projects mode selector, modify the 'INCLUDE' variable under the Build Environment variables list. Append the path to the libtorrent/include folder.

[image: Qt Build Environment Variables]

Comment: Hey. This will be weird: Months ago you asked a question about windows uxstyle themes having problems after lock. Did you find a solution? If you have, please add a solution in your original post. Sorry spamming here, but I couldn't reach you other way.

Comment: Sorry there mate, i couldn't find a proper solution for that other than applying the same theme again.

Comment: Thanks for responding here. :)